# Error "Warning: PID file not written; -detached was passed." Why does it keep happening?

Tags: rabbitmq

I'm very new to `RabbitMQ`. Following this [doc](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/brokers/rabbitmq.html#installing-rabbitmq-on-macos) provided from `Celery`, I installed it on Mac OS.

However, when I run `RabbitMQ` with the command `sudo rabbitmq-server`, it gives me a warning saying `"Warning: PID file not written; -detached was passed."` and `RabbitMQ` seems to be running well since I have a running message from `sudo rabbitmqctl status`.

Should I do something for the warning message?

Comment: You can ignore the warning. As per https://www.rabbitmq.com/rabbitmq-server.8.html#-detached you are running RMQ in background mode. Try starting/stopping RMQ using `sudo service rabbitmq-server start` and see if you still get that warning.

Comment: @Shiva Is `sudo service rabbitmq-server start` for Linux? If so, since I'm working on Mac, I ran `sudo rabbitmq-server`, this does NOT throw the warning. What is the `PID file` from the warning message by the way?

Comment: Yes, that was for linux. A pid file contains the process ID of a running process. One of the applications of writing the process ID to a file is to prevent running multiple instances of a process.